# multiple conditions for lookup in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. One with the City, dates and sales

```
sales = [['20101113','Miami',35],['20101114','New York',70],['20101114','Los Angeles',4],['20101115','Chicago',36],['20101114','Miami',12]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(sales,columns=['Date','City','Sales'])

print (df2)

       Date         City  Sales
0  20101113        Miami     35
1  20101114     New York     70
2  20101114  Los Angeles      4
3  20101115      Chicago     36
4  20101114        Miami     12
```

The second has some dates and cities.

```
date = [['20101114','New York'],['20101114','Los Angeles'],['20101114','Chicago']]

df = pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['Date','City'])

print (df)
```

I want to extract the sales from the first dataframe that match the city and and dates in the 3nd dataframe and add the sales to the 2nd dataframe. If the date is missing in the first table then the next highest date's sales should be retrieved.

The new dataframe should look like this

```
       Date         City  Sales

0  20101114     New York     70

1  20101114  Los Angeles      4

2  20101114      Chicago     36
```

I am having trouble extracting and merging tables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is `pd.merge_asof`, which allows you to join on a combination of exact matches and then a "close" match for some column.

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)

pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('Date'), 
              df2.sort_values('Date'), 
              by='City', on='Date',
              direction='forward')
```

#### Output:

```
        Date         City  Sales
0 2010-11-14     New York     70
1 2010-11-14  Los Angeles      4
2 2010-11-14      Chicago     36
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I am getting this error TypeError: merge_asof() got an unexpected keyword argument 'direction'

Comment: @19-a You have a very old version of `pandas` then. Can you upgrade it? Your issue is that: "The direction parameter was added in version 0.20.0 and introduces “forward” and “nearest”.